# Is it possible to let TS dynamically distinguish paths?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, tsconfig

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz82Y.png)
This is what my project looks like, in big project contains lots of small projects there, which share the build config and other common settings.

Now, I want to config the relate path, like '@'. I hope it to point to abc when it's inside the abc folder, and point to cba when it's inside the cba folder...

This can work on build config, and I am wondering if Typescript can support this behavior via tsconfig or some other workaround.

A clear representation of my problem is shown in this project.https://github.com/wuliqun/ts_paths

Comment: They should likely have their own inherited TS configs. As for Vite, likely should be custom resolver https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias

Comment: I found it hard to do so, because the outside universal tsconfig has some paths definitions, and "unfortunately there’s no way to merge paths from multiple tsconfig.json files", so the inside tsconfig paths definition cannot work.

Comment: This is very specific to your case then. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Comment: I've just created a github repository to show that, [https://github.com/wuliqun/ts_paths](https://github.com/wuliqun/ts_paths).  i would apreciate your help.